# Read office excel 2007 documents from within silverlight

Tags: silverlight, excel

I have a requirement to read in an excel 2007 file (*.xls) from within Silverlight, then extract data from this xls file. My background in web tech tells me this might be impossible to do, but I thought I would ask the question anyways.

The solution that comes to mind is to create a service which can handle this extraction, but this implementation is for a huge user global user base, and we're concerned about not having enough server resources, hence we're investigating client side options.

It will be a corporate intranet, but we the users are familiar with an exact xls file layout, and cannot convert before handing over to the Silverlight component.

1. So firstly, is this type of thing possible with Silverlight, I know it wasn't a few years ago
2. If its not possible out of the box, any 3rd party components, commercial or open source?
3. I've thought about writing a client side WCF app that will service requests from Silverlight in this way send the opened xls file to the WCF service app, process -> send results back. Do you think this is plausible?
4. If not Silverlight, could flash or a Java Applet handle conversion from xls to xml client side, and communicate this info to the silverlight app?
5. What about Microsoft Office Online, do you think its possible to get the file in binary format into the silver light app, then send it to open office, and get it back as xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit of clarity - *.xls* is Excel 2003 and before format (the binary format). *.xslx* is Excel 2007 and later format (the OpenXML format). If you're looking to do this with the 2007 format, it can be pretty easily achieved (well, at least compared to the 2003 format). So maybe clarifying which format you're after, or both, would be in order first as you listed "excel 2007 file (*.xls)" above.

Comment: Just to correct you - xlsx is Excel 2010, not 2007, 2003/2007 are binary, complex and proprietary format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating this, http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=576

Comment: You can read the doc as long as its in my documents. For most this is a show stopper. There are work arounds beyond the scope of this post which I am experimenting with.